# SQL Syntax Help: Returning the maximum value of a counted combination

Tags: sql, count, max

Imagine I had the following data in Table 1:

```
ID  Color   Toy  
----------------------
1   Red     Car  
2   Red     Truck  
3   Red     Truck  
4   Blue    Car  
5   Blue    Car  
6   Yellow  Airplane
```

And I wanted to return the maximum count of the most frequent toy for each color. How do I do this?

I've tried

```
SELECT 
    aa.color, aa.toy, MAX(aa.totalcount) AS maxcount 
FROM 
    (SELECT Color, Toy, COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
     FROM Table 1 
     GROUP BY Color, Toy) aa;
```

And for some reason that does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is the error I'm getting:

> An expression starting with "Color" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.. SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=4.25.1301

The desired output I want is one row per color with the toy that is the most frequent along with the count of the toy/color combination:

```
color   toy       count
-----------------------
Red     Truck     2     (NOT RED CAR)
Blue    Car       2
Yellow  Airplane  1
```

Comment: Which database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL, This query with GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER() should solve your issue. You can use the same logic for other databases as well.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Color,Toy,T Total, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Color,Toy ORDER BY T DESC) RN
    FROM(
        SELECT color,toy,count(*) T
        FROM your_table
        GROUP BY color,toy
    ) A
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: That is actually standard SQL and not specific to MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server offers a convenient method to do this without subqueries:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES Color, Toy, COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
FROM Table 1 
GROUP BY Color, Toy
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Color ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);
```